# Only show action buttons to logged in admin's in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm pretty new to Cake and am using Cake 2.0 and I have baked my views, controllers etc...

What I want to do is go into my views and wrap some logic around the `Edit` and `Delete` actions and only show them to logged in admins.

Does this sound like the correct approach? I have already locked down the actions so that only admins can access them but I don't want to show non-admins those buttons.

Also, I don't think having a separate view for normal users and admins is the correct approach but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the following code snippet in your AppController's beforeFilter() method:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
     $role = $this->Auth->user('role'); //If you are using Auth
     //$this->Session->read('User.role'); // If you are using a normal login session.
     if ($role == 'author' || $role == 'admin') { 
         $this->set('role', $role); 
     } 

     if($role == 'admin')
     {
         $this->set('is_admin', true);
     }
     else
     {
         $this->set('is_admin', false);
     }
    /***** your remaining code *******/
 }
```

And in your view just use the following:

```
 if($is_admin)
 {
      $this->Html->link('Admin Link', 'controllers/view');
 }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Is this method frowned upon or is it pretty common?

Comment: @bigmike7801 This is a common practice in Ruby On Rails, so I'd imagine it's perfectly fine to use in other MVC frameworks like CakePHP.

Answer (score 2):

It is ok to pass a variable to the view and check it to show the command.

controller:

```
...
$this->set('admin', true); //user is an admin and should view the links
...
```

view:

```
...
if ($admin){echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('action' => 'edit'))}
...
```